# Blank space Below footer

Tags: wordpress-theming, footer

I'm using twenty sixteen theme with elementor page builder in wordpress.. i'm facing issue in removing blank space below footer and unable to figureout  how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to share your page URL or where can I see the issue?
May be is there a "margin" or "padding" issue with CSS.